# Relation between left projections

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, baer-rings

Let $A$ be a Baer *-ring. Let $x$ be in $A$,  $L(x)$ is the left projection of $x$ that is the smallest projection with $L(x)x=x$.

> Q. Let $p,q$ are projections in $A$ with $p\leq q$. For a given projection $e$,  can we conclude $L(pe)\leq L(qe)$?